# Binding energy of a galaxy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, galaxies, binding-energy

I'm a novice in physics and new to the forms, so please forgive me if this is a dumb question or if this is in the wrong section to be posted, but how would one find the gravitational binding energy of our galaxy? I know their is a formula for a uniform sphere $U= 3GM^2/5r$, however I assume for a galaxy the method would be extremely different if its even possible to give an accurate figure.

So I ask this, what would be the necessary energy needed to break the binding energy of the galaxy with a well placed rapid release of energy (explosion), I know physics would say this hypothetical event is a big no no, but what would it be if this were a possibility?

Comment: An explosion is probably not the way to proceed if your goal is to unbind a galaxy. One could imagine calculating the escape velocity of each star in a galaxy and somehow applying an impulse to each sufficient to accomplish the escape. A more difficult issue would be how to unbind the dark matter in each galaxy.

Comment: If you have reasonable estimates for the matter and dark matter densities, then you could also produce reasonable estimates for the total gravitational binding energy. The thing is... do you count dark matter as part of your galaxy? If you do, there is probably almost no way of removing it. You can remove baryonic matter using non-gravitational interaction, but that would leave a probably mostly intact dark matter galaxy behind. To remove that you would need a giant gravitational "sweeper", which may take a very long time to get the job done.

Comment: I see, well what if this hypothetical event was just the energy needed to liberate all of the mass (excluding dark matter) to infinity, Could this work in mathematics at least?

Answer (score 1):

The first-order estimate of the gravitational binding energy of a galaxy can be obtained by approximating it as an uniform sphere using 
$$U=3GM^2/(5r).$$

Let's consider a large elliptical galaxy such as M87 as a concrete example. M87 hosts the supermassive black hole that was imaged with the Event Horizon Telescope. Within a distance of 32 kpc from the center, M87 contains a mass of $2 \times 10^{12} M_\odot$ where $M_\odot$ is a solar mass. Plugging in these two numbers in the equation for $U$ above, we get a binding energy of about $10^{61}$ erg (using CGS units as common in astrophysics).

It is not possible to dump all this energy at once throughout the galaxy and destroy it—gravitationally unbind it. However, if there is a physical process that over time transfers this amount of energy throughout the galaxy, it could considerably affect its properties, and *partly* destroy it.

Astrophysicists think that the supermassive black holes located at the centers of galaxies dump large amounts of energy in their surroundings while they are growing (being fed with gas). This energy is transferred from the black hole to the galaxy through gas outflows and radiation.

A supermassive black hole dumps an estimated energy of $$E=0.1 M_{\rm BH} c^2 = 2 \times 10^{61} \left( \frac{M}{10^8 M_\odot} \right) \ {\rm erg}$$ while it is growing into the galaxy (I will not get into the details of how I estimated this, it is a rough estimate). This energy is not released all at once, but takes tens of millions of years to be generated. Tens of millions of years is not a long time compared to the lifetime of a galaxy.

The conclusion is that the energy released by the central black hole during a galaxy's evolution is comparable to its gravitational binding energy. Therefore, supermassive black holes can potentially change the global properties of galaxies with their energy release. This effect has a name in astrophysics—**AGN feedback** (AGN stands for *active galactic nuclei*)—and is a current area of research.